# count() with select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a parquet file on spark which i'm converting to a tempTable with three columns,Flight number, Origin airport and delay in departure. The flights which were not delayed has a value 0(zero) in delay column, rest have number of minutes by which flight was delayed in them. I want to calculate percentage of flights delayed per airport.

One way I am trying to do this is by getting total flights for an airport and dividing that number with number of flights delayed for that airport. Here is the query i'm using:

> select Origin as cur_origin, count(Origin) as totalCount, (select count(*) FROM flightData WHERE Origin=cur_origin AND DepDelay>0) as delayedCount FROM flightData GROUP BY Origin;

P.S. In above query i'm not dividing the two numbers, but just trying to display them for debugging.

But, this give me error: unresolved operator Aggregate Origin

can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong, or any other solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, although you may have trouble with the count(Origin) since that's your group by column.

```
select 
    Origin as cur_origin, 
    count(Origin) as totalCount, 
    sum(if(DepDelay > 0,1,0)) as delayedCount 
FROM flightData 
GROUP BY Origin
```